# Executing sql command in a view in mysql

Tags: mysql, view

I have this view    `create view MYVIEW as select * from MYTABLE`  ,
I'm wondering if i execute a SELECT request on the view MYVIEW,the real sql commande will be done on the view or the table MYTABLE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view is as it states, only a view. The actual select command will execute on the underlying table(s)

What needs to be noted is

[Updatable and Insertable Views](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/view-updatability.html)

> Some views are updatable. That is, you can use them in statements such
>   as UPDATE, DELETE, or INSERT to update the contents of the underlying
>   table. For a view to be updatable, there must be a one-to-one
>   relationship between the rows in the view and the rows in the
>   underlying table. There are also certain other constructs that make a
>   view nonupdatable. To be more specific, a view is not updatable if it
>   contains any of the following:

and then a big list follows.